# List access synchronization in GAE

Tags: java, google-app-engine, synchronization, jdo, datanucleus

I just synchronized my java code to avoid multiple access to the same List. Here it is my code:

```
List<Category> list = Collections.synchronizedList(listCat); 
..
pm.currentTransaction().begin();
..
synchronized (list) {
    for (Category category : list) {
        category.setKey(null);
        tempUser.addToCategories(category);
    }
}
..
pm.currentTransaction().commit();
```

.. but I continue to get

```
java.util.ConcurrentModificationException: too much contention on these datastore entities. please try again.
at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreApiHelper.translateError(DatastoreApiHelper.java:39)
at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreApiHelper$1.convertException(DatastoreApiHelper.java:76)
at com.google.appengine.api.utils.FutureWrapper.get(FutureWrapper.java:106)
at com.google.appengine.api.utils.FutureWrapper.get(FutureWrapper.java:90)
at com.google.appengine.api.utils.FutureWrapper.get(FutureWrapper.java:90)
at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.FutureHelper.getInternal(FutureHelper.java:72)
at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.FutureHelper.quietGet(FutureHelper.java:33)
at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:116)
at org.datanucleus.store.appengine.jdo.DatastoreJDOTransaction.commit(DatastoreJDOTransaction.java:68)
at (the row where the transaction is committed)
```

.. when different instances access to that list. 
Is there a way to avoid that? I mean a different way from the one specified here:
[Uses for Transactions](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/transactions#Uses_for_Transactions).

I use JDO 2.3, but I don't think it affects in anyway this behaviour

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GAE transactions don't do locking: they use [optimistic concurrency control](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/transactions#What_Can_Be_Done_In_a_Transaction), meaning if multiple transactions change same entity group the first will succeed the others will fail and will need to be retried.

Comment: uhm.. so all the synchronization are unuseful? The only way is catch the exception and retry?

Comment: Java synchronization works within JVM. It does not work across multiple GAE instances. So it's not useful in distributed environments such as GAE.

Comment: ok clear: at the end (as requested in my question) there is no other way other than wrap the ConcurrentException and retry .. right?